# Is 1 minute enough time to determine a question's fate?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691600/starting-a-method-in-another-activity-like-a-service) and the fact it was tagged as too broad only 1 min. after its inception. Is that enough time to put a question on hold? Aside from the ridiculous posts that obviously need to be shut down immediately, I've never seen one put on hold so fast.

Comment: codeMagic has the answer nailed here. This is still a good question, too! Kind of the root here is that one thing I occasionally do is troll the brand new questions for chances to vote, comment, edit, close, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, I would say no. But here, yes because when it was put on hold, there was absolutely no code and the question was **very** broad. This user also is starting a pattern of asking very poor questions and not responding well.

If you look at the OP's previous question, you will see what I mean. I almost voted to reopen after the code was added but, until I saw more cooperation from the OP, I didn't feel good about voting to reopen. The question is still "too broad" and unclear.

Comment: Well, I didn't think about user history. I assumed each question was judged independently, but that's a good point. Perhaps I read too much into the question, it seemed like op was asking about starting an activity for result. When I asked if that was the case, op said yes. I agree it's not the best question, but to get immediate moderation is not common in my experience.

Comment: I had just dealt with the user not long before that question was posted so it was easy for me to understand the history. I saw your comment when you left it and I would say it may be a safe assumption if I didn't know the history already.

Comment: Also, incidentally, I considered only that question when closing it. And it took me much less than a minute to actually decide in this case.

Comment: Oh, and by way of explanation for the speed; I do occasionally troll the new questions.